# Why is IE11 Ignoring Conditional Comment

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I'm running IE11 on windows 8.1. I have the following header in a page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'><![endif]-->
```

Am i loosing my mind or does IE11 now ignore these conditional comments? The reason i am inclosing this in the comments so to help with html validation. If i remove the comment it works as expected.

Comment: Why do you even need the conditional comment to guard around it, given it's already targeted to IE?

Comment: IE 10 and 11 **do not** interpret conditional comments anymore!

Comment: The reason for the comment is so that the page validates html validators.

Comment: Conditional comments were a fine example of two wrongs _do_ make a right. Comments are _supposed_ to be ignored, but Microsoft ignored that. On the other hand, you needed these comments to compensate for the other weaknesses in IE. The problem now is that IE & Edge still have many holes in them, and you no longer have an easy way to address them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

MS has dropped conditional comments as of IE10. http://www.sitepoint.com/microsoft-drop-ie10-conditional-comments/.

Comment: @RBloeth - That was a bug that is now fixed.

Comment: What about an actual **solution**?